# Why does SOSL return a List of a List of sObjects in Apex?

Tags: apex, sosl

When I use SOSL in Apex (`search.query();`) the return type is `List<List<sObject>>`, but I've never run across a case in which there is more than one list returned.

For example, this:

```
string q= 'FIND {"John Doe"} Returning Contact(Id, Email, Name, Account.Name)';
List<List<sObject>> ListOfListOfSObjects = search.query(q);

system.debug('Number of Lists: '+ListOfListOfSObjects.size());
for(Integer i=0; i<ListOfListOfSObjects.size(); i++)
{
    system.debug('List '+(i+1)+' size: '+ListOfListOfSObjects[i].size());
}
```

Returns:

```
16:18:42.137 (137179000)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|Number of Lists: 1
16:18:42.137 (137575000)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|List 1 size: 2
```

When would SOSL return more than one List of sObjects? Did I miss something in the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index.htm)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SOSL has the ability to search across multiple objects in one query. So if you do something like the following it will return results from Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, and Leads.

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND 'map*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account (Id, Name), Contact, Opportunity, Lead];
Account [] accounts = ((List<Account>)searchList[0]);
Contact [] contacts = ((List<Contact>)searchList[1]);
Opportunity [] opportunities = ((List<Opportunity>)searchList[2]);
Lead [] leads = ((List<Lead>)searchList[3]);
```