# SOSL - Combining results from multiple objects into a single result set

Tags: apex, sosl

If you query from multiple objects the SOSL query returns a `List<List<SObject>>`, with each inner List sorted by relevance inside.
I want to return a combined mixed list sorted by relevance between all objects.. one way to do it would be just combine all these results in apex and then sort by date (but date isn't exactly relevance) - is there a better way to do that, preferably in a single query?

Let's say I have these results:

```
Case
  Case 1
  Case 2
Task
  Task 1
  Task 2
```

I want them returned as (or whatever, based on relevance among all results combined):

```
Task 2
Case 1
Case 2
Task 1
```

SOSL format:
[Why does SOSL return a List of a List of sObjects in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/why-does-sosl-return-a-list-of-a-list-of-sobjects-in-apex)

Single object SOSL query:
[How to order SOSL results by relevance](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15440/how-to-order-sosl-results-by-relevance)

Comment: I don't see anything like `WITH RELEVANCE` in the [SOSL Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax.htm) so that information may not be available. Will be interesting to see if there is an answer...

Comment: Perhaps if you first show us how you intend to combine them into a single list, that might help someone come up with an idea of how to sort them using comparable. I'd expect you to first need to create a wraper class of some kind since SOSL doesn't return an AggregateResults Query that I'm aware of on Objects. It would seem the next step would be to execute your sort method within the wrapper.

Comment: @crmprogdev, for instance you have a navigation menu displaying your search results, and you have a selection option for each object type to filter, and above each option you have "most popular" or "top results" or something, showing you a list of all of the most relevant items to the search term, and not split by groups.. but those items need to be from specific object types.

Comment: @Poster I understood that you'd be querying multiple objects. What I was saying is "let's see your code" on how you plan to combine your lists into a single list so you can begin to sort them. You first need to create some kind of wrapper class to hold your results. Show us your code and what you've tried. Don't ask us to write all of your code for you.

Comment: I don't think your request is possible. You can assess the relative priority between items in a list. You can assess the relative priority between lists. But you cannot assess the relative priority between items in separate lists. Since the relevance indicator is not exposed, the only way is guesswork.

Comment: @crmprogdev not really sure how you got from my question to me asking people to write all my code for me, nor why this question was marked as off-topic.
I didn't ask how to combine results, nor to show me code that combines them, I asked whether and what way there is to sort by relevance.. if there's some sort of indicator to determine relevance between different lists - without knowing that, I can't even start writing any code because there's nothing to base it on.
As some people already mentioned, looks like this is impossible and there will be a need to invent some sort of algorithm.

Comment: @Poster My point was, that if you couldn't show us how you'd combine your lists as a starting point, you hadn't put thought and effort into trying to solve the problem for yourself. Being able to show how to combine them might have provided someone with an idea of how to sort them. Otherwise, they'd have had to combine them for you to be able to sort them; essentially writing all of your code for you. Just my opinion which others apparently agreed with.